# Symfony2: How to add FormType

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have an Entity `Product` and I have an Entity `File`.
The relationship between those 2 is normally a ManyToMany Relation. But I need also a field Value "`sorting`" and "`description`", so I must declare my own JoinTable `ProductHasFile`. Now I want in my Form, that I can have a `Product` bute include the `File` FormTpye an not the `ProductHasFile` FormType.

Product Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Product")
 */
class Product
{

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductHasFile", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"}))
     */
     private $productHasFiles;
....
```

File Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductHasFile", mappedBy="file")
     */
    private $productHasFiles;
...
```

And my own generated Entity ProductHasFile:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ProductHasFile")
 */
class ProductHasFile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
    */
    private $sorting;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    private $description;

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productHasFiles")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
   private $product;

   /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File", inversedBy="productHasFiles")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
   private $file;
```

When I now make my Formtype for Product:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
           ->add('productHasFiles', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => ProductHasFileType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    ,
                )
            )
```

and my FormType for ProductHasFileType:

```
class ProductHasFileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /**
         * @var $entityManager EntityManager
         */
        $fileRepository = $options['fileRepository'];

        $builder
            ->add('sorting', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add('file', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\File',
                'label' => 'file',
            ))
        ;
```

I get only a dropdwon for the File Entity. But I want to have my full `File FormType` which has the Uploadfield and other things, it looks like this:

```
class FileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'description',
            ))
            ->add('type', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'type',
            ))
          ->add('file', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'file',

                ))
        ;
    }
```

Does anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Symfony doc about [how to embed forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html) this is as easy as

```
class ProductHasFileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /**
         * @var $entityManager EntityManager
         */
        $fileRepository = $options['fileRepository'];

        $builder
            ->add('sorting', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add('file', FileType::class) //where FileType is your own FormType
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ProductHasFileType` you're adding your file like this:

```
->add('file', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\File',
            'label' => 'file',
        ))
```

so you are adding your file as `entity` type wich logically renders a dropdown of all file entities.

What you need to do is pass your own `FileType`.To make sure you are using your own file type and not the default symfony one don't forget to add the correct use statement.

result:

```
use MyBundle\Form\Type\FileType;

class ProductHasFileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sorting', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add('file', FileType::class)
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.Please consider accepting my answer so that others may benefit from it.Happy programming